# Storing values in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, hashtable

I am trying to store values in php, like a HashTable with multiple keys. For example I am I would want this to return two different values:

```
$value1=$content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typea'];

$value2=$content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typeb'];
```

What would be the best way to go about implementing a feature like this?

Comment: What is the question exactly ? How to create an associative array with several depth levels ?

Comment: then implement that way?

Comment: Yes, or if there is something else I should use besides arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building a complicated array, how about you define and use a simple class instead?  e.g:

```
<?php
class beer {
  var $brand;
  var $ounces;
  var $container;
}

$mybeer = new beer();
$mybeer->brand = "Coors";
$mybeer->ounces = 12;
$mybeer->container = "can";

echo $mybeer->brand;
echo $mybeer->ounces;
echo $mybeer->container;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set values the same way you get them.

```
$content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typea'] = $value1;
$content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typeb'] = $value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of PHP being a dynamic scripting language by letting it create your desired array structure automatically:

```
 $content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typea'] = "value1";
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to make a unique key based on the various keys and store it in one big array.

Instead of this,

```
$value1=$content['var1']['var2']['var3']['typea'];
```

you'd have something like this...

```
$contentKey = generateKey("var1", "var2", "var3", "typeA");
$value1 = $content[$contentKey];
```

where `generateKey` would do something like hash the various inputs, or concatenate them together with some unique delimiter like a quadruple underscore.  This would require fewer array lookups than the other solutions, and (in my opinion) is easier to read.